# Find NAs in array[,,i] dimensions and mark their positions as NA in a matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, na

I am struggling with something that is really easy to understand but that I could not solve yet my R skills.

Let's assume I have got the following array:

```
mat1 = as.matrix(data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), col2 = c(2,3,'NA',5,6,7,8,9), col3 = c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), col4 = c(2,3,4,1,2,6,7,8),
                          col5 = c(2,3,'NA','NA',6,7,8,9), col6 = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9), col7 = c(1,2,3,4,6,7,'NA','NA'), col8 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,'NA','NA')))


mat2 = as.matrix(data.frame(col1 = c('NA',2,3,4,5,6,7,8), col2 = c(2,3,1,5,6,7,8,9), col3 = c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'NA'), col4 = c(2,3,4,1,2,6,7,8),
                 col5 = c(2,3,11,88,6,7,8,9), col6 = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9), col7 = c(1,2,3,4,6,7,'NA','NA'), col8 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,'NA','NA')))

#ignore warnings
class(mat1) = 'numeric'
class(mat2) = 'numeric'

my_array = array(c(mat1, mat2), dim = c(8,8,2))
print(my_array)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    2    2    1    1    1
[2,]    2    3    4    3    3    2    2    2
[3,]    3   NA    5    4   NA    3    3    3
[4,]    4    5    6    1   NA    5    4    4
[5,]    5    6    7    2    6    6    6    5
[6,]    6    7    8    6    7    7    7    6
[7,]    7    8    9    7    8    8   NA   NA
[8,]    8    9   10    8    9    9   NA   NA

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]   NA    2    3    2    2    1    1    1
[2,]    2    3    4    3    3    2    2    2
[3,]    3    1    5    4   11    3    3    3
[4,]    4    5    6    1   88    5    4    4
[5,]    5    6    7    2    6    6    6    5
[6,]    6    7    8    6    7    7    7    6
[7,]    7    8    9    7    8    8   NA   NA
[8,]    8    9   NA    8    9    9   NA   NA
```

And the following matrix:

```
mat3 = matrix(seq(1,64,1), nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
print(mat3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    9   17   25   33   41   49   57
[2,]    2   10   18   26   34   42   50   58
[3,]    3   11   19   27   35   43   51   59
[4,]    4   12   20   28   36   44   52   60
[5,]    5   13   21   29   37   45   53   61
[6,]    6   14   22   30   38   46   54   62
[7,]    7   15   23   31   39   47   55   63
[8,]    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64
```

In `mat3`, I need to convert to NA the observations that are NA in both `my_array[,,i]` dimensions, where `i = 1,2`.

My expected output would be:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    9   17   25   33   41   49   57
[2,]    2   10   18   26   34   42   50   58
[3,]    3   11   19   27   35   43   51   59
[4,]    4   12   20   28   36   44   52   60
[5,]    5   13   21   29   37   45   53   61
[6,]    6   14   22   30   38   46   54   62
[7,]    7   15   23   31   39   47   NA   NA
[8,]    8   16   24   32   40   48   NA   NA
```

My real array has got `i = 1:1000`.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
mat3[which(is.na(mat1)*is.na(mat2)==1,arr.ind = TRUE,useNames = FALSE)]=NA
```

or this one:

```
mat3[which(is.na(my_array[,,2])*is.na(my_array[,,1])==1,arr.ind = TRUE,useNames = FALSE)]=NA
```

---

for 1 to 1000 dimension:

```
mat3[which(apply(is.na(my_array),FUN = prod,MARGIN = 1:2)==1,arr.ind = TRUE,useNames = FALSE)]=NA
```

Comment: my real array has got i = 1:1000. I can't apply your solution

Comment: so you can use this code: `mat3[which(apply(is.na(my_array),FUN = prod,MARGIN = 1:1000)==1,arr.ind = TRUE,useNames = FALSE)]=NA`

Comment: hi, it doesn't work with i = 1:1000. I got the following error: Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: sorry this is the correct one:
`mat3[which(apply(is.na(my_array),FUN = prod,MARGIN = 1:2)==1,arr.ind = TRUE,useNames = FALSE)]=NA `